# SVG text writing direction

Tags: css, svg

Consider the following svg containing an RTL text:

```html
<svg viewBox='0 0 1024 80'  >
  <rect x='1' y='1' width='1022' height='78' style='fill:#fff;stroke:#3fa9f5;'></rect>
  <text style='dominant-baseline:text-before-edge;font-size:65px'>مرحبا</text>
</svg>
```

it displays like the following:
[image]

I am trying to make it display like the following without explicit positioning or transforms:
[image]

What I tried:

I looked at the [direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/direction) attribute but the text went off the screen.

Also tried css [writing-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode) same happened with writing-mode:tb-rl

My question is, is there a way to do it without explicit positioning or explicit transforms, I only care about the latest version of chrome?

Comment: The text is drawn at 0, 0 because those are the lacuna values. It's not going to display at 1022, 0 unless you tell it to somehow either via explicit positioning or transforms.

Comment: @RobertLongson thanks a lot, just wanted to make sure its not possible before having to do it with transforms, I was able to build a full featured textbox, support for LTR languages was possible without any transforms or explicit positioning so I thought I could do the same for RTL languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SVG is not HTML.  Elements are positioned where you tell them. There is no automatic layout like there is in HTML.

You can use `direction="rtl"`, but as Robert says, you still have to position it appropriately for the situation.

```html
<svg viewBox='0 0 1024 80'  >
  <rect x='1' y='1' width='1022' height='78' style='fill:#fff;stroke:#3fa9f5;'></rect>
  <text style='dominant-baseline:text-before-edge;font-size:65px' x="1024" direction="rtl">مرحبا</text>
</svg>
```